# Trying to use StopWatch outside a method

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I'm trying to create a stop watch form. I want to be able to have a button I press to get a Lap time just like a normal stop watch. For reasons I don't understand I can't define a Stopwatch variable and call it's constructor in another method. How would I go about making a `StopWatch` variable so that I can use it in other methods? If I'm not supposed to use a `StopWatch` what should I be doing?

```
namespace _Hard0002_StopWatch {
    public partial class StopWatch : Form {
        StateEnum state;
        StopWatch stopWatch;

        public StopWatch() {
            InitializeComponent();
            state = StateEnum.Stoped;
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (state == StateEnum.Stoped) {
                stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                state = StateEnum.Started;
                ChangeFormTittle("Started");
                TimeKeeperText.Text = "0.0";
            }
        }

    private void LapButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //save time elapsed to a string array
        stopWatch.getElapsedTime()//I know this isn't how you call it I just worded it to be readable.
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try to declare `stopWatch` in my `StartButton_Click()`

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch' to '_Hard0002_StopWatch.StopWatch'`

Comment: Probably best not to name the form the same as `StopWatch`

Comment: Also `StopWatch` is intended to be a high-precision timer (usually used for performance benchmarking). You could easily get away with a simple timer here.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll look into timer as well. I just want to get `StopWatch` working just because I've been stuck on it for  while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C#`'s stopwatch is `Stopwatch`.  Your class is `StopWatch`.  You declare your variable:

```
StopWatch stopWatch;
```

then initialize it:

```
stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

using two different objects.  Best to rename your form to something like `StopwatchForm` to prevent from confusing yourself more.

Comment: It is possible, if you prepend the objects in the right way: `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch stopWatch` and `stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.StopWatch()`, in cases you really want it. But this can be very confusing and leads to long statements. Better not to do it, but it is possible that you might see it in code elsewhere. For example, 3 timers exist, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`.